# Minus class from stored variable

Tags: jquery, html, class

I have a variable which is the HTML of a UL, I was wondering if I can remove a few things from the variable but not the actual HTML of the UL..??

EG

```
<ol class='sortable'>
    <li class="menu-item">
        <div>Allure</div>
        <ol>
            <li class="menu-item" style="display: list-item;">
                <div><a href="/_webapp_4002836/Allure-Gallery">Energy-Drink</a>      </div>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>

    <li class="menu-item disabled">
        <div>Bitten SJP</div>
        <ol>
            <li class="menu-item" style="display: list-item;">
                <div><a href="#">Bitten</a></div>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

My JQuery does this

```
var sortableList = $(".sortable").html();
```

is there any way to do this

```
var sortableList = $(".sortable").html("MINUS ALL CLASSES ".DISABLED");
```

Thanks for any answers

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to accomplish in terms of the HTML instead in terms of your current approach. There is probably a better way and the question is a little unclear.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle to try a few things, I've changed my approach but not the overall goal, to remove something from the variable... http://jsfiddle.net/Rfk6M/2/

Comment: I want to remove this <input type='checkbox' name='selected' class='select> from the variable that is storing the HTML of the OL. I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to select all of a menu-item that is directly from `.sortable` that isn't disabled:

```
$(".sortable > .menu-item:not(.disabled)")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can ensure that the word `disabled` will not appear in somewhere in text it should be save to use `replace("disabled","")` on a *copy* of the string ie:

```
var sortableList = $(".sortable").html();
newSortable = sortableList.replace("disabled","");
$("body").append(newSortable)
```

But why can't you do it with `removeClass`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want the markup for ol without li.disabled in it.

```
var sortableList = $(".sortable").find("li:not(.disabled)").wrap('<ol class="sortable" />').html();
```

Answer (score 0):

This example separates the html from the dom so you don't manipulate the dom: http://jsfiddle.net/Rfk6M/1/

```
var html = $(".sortable").clone().html();
html = $(html).each(function(){
   $(this).removeClass();
}).html();
```

If you want to manipulate the dom use this:

```
var html = $(".sortable").html();
html = $(html).each(function(){
   $(this).removeClass();
}).html();
```